# Insert statement with where condition throws error

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, sql-insert

The following SQL statement throws error in Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ACCT_NB, ACCT_TYPE, TOKEN_ID)
SELECT ACCT_NB, 'A', ID FROM TABLE2
WHERE NOT IN (SELECT ACCT_NB FROM TABLE1 
              WHERE ACCT_TYPE='A' AND TABLE1.ACCT_NB=TABLE2.ACCT_NB)
```

SQL command not ended properly. 
Please help out on correcting the query

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the left hand side of the `not in` operator. I assume it's supposed to be `ACCT_NB`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ACCT_NB, ACCT_TYPE, TOKEN_ID)
SELECT ACCT_NB, 'A', ID 
FROM   TABLE2
WHERE  ACCT_NB NOT IN (SELECT ACCT_NB 
                       FROM   TABLE1 
                       WHERE  ACCT_TYPE='A' AND TABLE1.ACCT_NB=TABLE2.ACCT_NB)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(ACCT_NB, ACCT_TYPE, TOKEN_ID)
    SELECT ACCT_NB, 'A', ID
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM TABLE1 
                      WHERE ACCT_TYPE = 'A' AND TABLE1.ACCT_NB = TABLE2.ACCT_NB
                     );
```

I prefer `not exists` to `not in` because of how they handle `NULL`s different.  `NOT IN` will never return true if the subquery selects even one `NULL` value.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how `NULL` is handled differently? Thanks.